# C: Largest number, wrong output. rand()

Tags: c, arrays, random

This program creates random numbers using rand(). The user inputs how many random numbers will be created as an integer. The program also finds the largest number.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

  int main(void)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int size;
  int i;
  int array[0];

  printf("\nSize of random array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  for (i = 0; i <  size; i++){
    array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;;
  }

  for (i=0; i < size; i++){
       printf("%d ", array[i]);
      }

 int largest =0;

for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
      if (largest < array[i])
              largest = array[i];
      }
printf("\n largest element present in the given array is : %d\n", largest);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using an online C compiler. (I was using Atom editor but my code doesn't do anything in there).
The output should be something like this:

> Size of random array: 6
>   0 6 10 21
>   largest element present in the given array is : 21

But I'm getting this:

> Size of random array: 6
>   0 6 0 0 -433525051 32757
>   largest element present in the given array is : 32757

Why do I'm getting such a big numbers? how can I fix this?

Comment: You are defining a zero-size array (which is illegal in standard c by itself) and then accessing it out of bounds. Your code if full of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What do you expect accessing, for example, `array[12]` would do given `int array[0];`?

Comment: Some people are telling you to allocate the array on the heap.  You could also look at using a Variable Length Array if you are using C99 (and probably if using C11).

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: 1) zero length arrays not allowed in ISO C. 2) this statement: `array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;;` will write beyond the end of the array.  Result is undefined behavior. 3) this statement: `printf("%d ", array[i]);` will access beyond the end of the array.  Result is undefined behavior. ... there are more examples of undefined behavior in the code

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this statement: `srand(time(NULL));` should be: `srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );` to avoid the compiler outputting a warning message about type conversions

Answer (score 3):

For C, you have the either statically allocate memory at the beginning or dynamically allocate it with malloc/calloc (there are a few other methods). Since you are reading in the user's size array, dynamic memory allocation is probably the way to go. There are some things to keep in mind with dynamically allocating memory. You always have to check that the allocation was successful and free your memory. You can read more here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm

Sample solution using OP's sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

srand(time(NULL));
int size = 0;
int i;
int largest;
// You must declare a pointer to allocate space on the heap
int *array; 

// Loop until user enters a valid size
while (size <= 0) {

    printf("\nPlease enter the size of random array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    if (size <= 0) 
      printf("Please enter a number above 0.");

}

// Set the size as your input size  
array = malloc(sizeof(int) * size); 

// Always check if your memory allocation was successful...
// Probably better ways to handle than to simply exit out
if(array == NULL) {

    printf("malloc of size %d failed!\n", size);
    exit(1); 

}

for (i = 0; i <  size; i++) {

  array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;;

}

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

  printf("%d ", array[i]);

}

// Set the largest value as the first element in the arr
largest = array[0]; 

for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {

  if (largest < array[i]) {
        largest = array[i];
  }
}

printf("\nLargest element present in the given array is : %d\n", largest);

// Always FREE your allocated memory
free(array); 

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should check the input value for `int size` which must be `size >= 1`. Why start the `largest` loop from `i = 1`? Did you mean to initialise `int largest = array[0]`? Otherwise this is a reasonable answer, but your code formatting is poor.

Comment: @WeatherVane I used the OP's code block and added the bare basics of dynamic memory allocation because that was their question. I did not reformat the OP's code or do other error checks because it did not pertain to the question. I do agree that one definitely should check the size though, thanks, I will edit that.

Comment: If you submit a pat answer it should be a good example, please don't be defensive. The loop is still incorrect.

Comment: Sorry if I came across as being defensive...I am new the SOF and will keep your advice in mind.

Comment: I just pushed the changes @WeatherVane.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making is more difficult to understand, debug, etc and during debugging/maintenance is error prone

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring an array of `int` types that holds 0 elements: `int array[0];`

Instead, you either need to allocate the memory on the heap using [`malloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) (and subsequently [`free`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html)), or you need to declare an array of a specific size and limit the user.

Example:

```
int* array; // <- declare a pointer

printf("\nSize of random array: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

array = malloc(sizeof(int)*size); // sizeof(int) * size gives us enough memory
// do something with array then free when done
free(array);
```

Or

```
int array[255]; // max of 255 elements

printf("\nSize of random array: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

if (size > 255) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Size greater than max\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Accessing an element outside of the bounds of an array leads to undefined behavior; in other words, it *might* work as expected, or it *might* return complete garbage (which is happening in your case).

Hope that can help.